# Alternative image for iframe video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, alt

So I want to have an alternative for my iframe youtube video, so if the video is not loading cuz of internet connection, it shall load an alt image from the localhost.

```html
<iframe width="95%" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OA318VbEhtc?&rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: How would page or image in page load if no internet connection? Is this in a PWA that has a serviceworker registered? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use alt image on iframe tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776296/how-to-use-alt-image-on-iframe-tag)

Comment: @charlietfl it is just a web application and the video is the only thing which needs internet connection, the rest of the files are loaded from the root/folder where the html/js/css files are located. So if the video doesn't show up cuz of Internet I want to show an image instead

Comment: @weibenfalk not exactly. well let's say, instead of getting the 404 or 200 or no internet connection error in the iframe, I want to load a custom error image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple answer for this, using this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>            
function updateOnlineStatus() {
document.getElementById('video').src = "HERE COMES THE YT LINK";
document.getElementById('video').style.backgroundImage = "";
}

function updateOfflineStatus() {
document.getElementById('video').style.backgroundImage = "url(PATH TO A CUSTOM ERROR 
IMAGE)";
document.getElementById('video').src = "";
}

window.addEventListener('online', updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOfflineStatus); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="video" width="95%" height="320" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<script>
if(navigator.onLine){
document.getElementById('video').src = "HERE COMES THE YT LINK";
document.getElementById('video').style.backgroundImage = "";
} else {
document.getElementById('video').style.backgroundImage = "PATH TO A CUSTOM ERROR 
IMAGE";
document.getElementById('video').src = "";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This checks first of all once the page loads, if there is an internet connection or not. If it's offline the video source will be removed and you will be only able to see the background image (custom made error page) and if the internet connection get's off or on after loading the page, the event listener will check online/offline status again and do the right changes.

Comment: How would this work on mobile, where the connection is On, but iframe container video autoplayed in the background in a DIV is blocked?

Answer (score -1):

If there is no Internet connection, the page will not load. So, you can't use `alt=''`  or have an alternative image.
Sorry! :(

Comment: there is no alt attributes for <iframe>

Comment: well, how are you checking it? anyway, if the internet isn't working, the 'no internet' error page will come up